# Laravel Caching Model with Eager Loading

Tags: laravel, caching, model

I am trying to cache certain models (I am using cache file driver) in my project. When I load Model::all() laravel debug bar shows 4 queries (the model and the `protected $with` attribute). I am doing this using a trait that I called Cacheable.

Trait:

```php
namespace App\Cache\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cache;

trait Cacheable {
    public static function bootCacheable() {

        static::saved(function (Model $model) {
            Cache::forever(md5(get_class($model).$model->id)), $model);
        });

        static::deleted(function (Model $model)
        {
            Cache::forget(md5(get_class($model).$model->id));
        });

        static::updated(function (Model $model) {
            Cache::forever(md5(get_class($model).$model->id), $model);
        });

        static::retrieved(function (Model $model) {
            Cache::forever(md5(get_class($model).$model->id), $model);
        });
    }
}
```

Model:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Classes\ChallengeStatus;
use App\Cache\Traits\Cacheable;

class Challenge extends Model
{
    use Cacheable;

    protected $with = ['platform', 'brand', 'challengeType'];

    public function platform() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Platform');
    }

    public function brand() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Brand');
    }

    public function challengeType() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ChallengeType');
    }

    public function reports() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Report');
    }
}
```

What am I missing on this approach? I can't figure it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You're only setting the model in the cache, never retrieving it.

Comment: Could you point me how to do this?? I am still learning how to use the Cache, and I am a bit lost, give me an example, I beg you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem statement correctly, you are eager loading relations and multiple queries are executed to retrieve the data.
This issue does not have anything with your Cacheable trait.

Laravel query builder always uses multiple queries to load eager loaded relations.

Unfortunately, it **does not** merge sql queries to create a bigger sql query and then extract the records.

Comment: No, I am just trying to cache the model ir order to avoid repeatable queries. As @DigitalDrifter did say, my code works (I can see models cached in the storage/framework folder) but I do not have a retrieve method. Thats what I am lloking for, how to put the retrieve method in that trait. With that trait finished I could use it in all the models I need to cache.